# Perform silent installation programmatically using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-services, exe, silent-installer

I have an installer of an application,say app_installer.exe. I am able to silently install it to my system from `cmd` using `app_installer.exe /S`. Now I need to do the same from a Windows service and I created a service application for this in `MSVS 2013`. I tried using`CreateProcess()` in the following manner:

```
if (CreateProcess(NULL,"E:\\app_installer.exe \S",NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo))
    {
        myfile << "Wait for object...\n";
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    myfile << "Handles closed\n";

    }
    else
    {
        myfile << "The process could not be started...\n";
        myfile << GetLastError();
    }
```

Though `CreateProcess`(I also tried /SD,/silent,/q,/qn instead of /S) returned a non-zero value, my application was not installed.
Then I added the following line to my code:

```
system("E:\\app_installer.exe \S \norestart);
```

On adding this line,after starting the `service`, it asked me whether to `view the message` from the service and when I clicked on `View message`, the installation wizard came.. However, it is not silent...

Is it the problem with the parameters that I passed? How can silent installation proceed in C++?

Comment: You need to escape your backslash characters with another backslash.

Comment: @Galik: in CreateProcess or system?

Comment: In all string literals unless you are using the `C++11` raw string literals.

Comment: @Galik: I added it.. still the installation is  not silent :(

Comment: Think about how the compiler is supposed to differentiate between an end of line character `'\n'` and a back slash character `'\'`? You have to escape the back slach character with another back slash like: `'\\'`.

Comment: Try either: `"E:\\app_installer.exe \\S  \\norestart"` or, alternatively `"E:/app_installer.exe /S  /norestart"` (windows should accept forward slash too).

Comment: Tried it.. installation wizard appears...

Comment: @Galik: the correct string is most likely to be `"E:\\app_installer.exe /S /norestart"` (you can't depend on Windows accepting forward slash in a path, it only works sometimes)

Comment: Note that some installers just won't work in a service context, though such problems are fortunately rare.  Still, it would probably be simpler to troubleshoot your code as a conventional application first, and only once that is working try to turn it into a service.

Comment: Also, have you tried `/S /norestart` from the interactive command line?  That is, do you know for sure that the installer actually accepts `/norestart` as a flag?

Comment: @Harry Actually no.from commandline I only tried /S..since it was working fine,it didnt bother me. It was when I couldnt start it programatically, I searched for other flags.. i ll try it.. also did u mean to write a simple cpp pgm to run the installer silently?

Comment: Yes, basically just a main() containing the code you posted.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: yes..it is possible to silently install from a simple C++ program(containing only a  `main()`) using `system("E:\\app_installer.exe /S");`. But the same command in WinService gives the interactive installer...

Comment: Could be a bug in system().  Now that you know the command string to use, try using CreateProcess again.  But it could also be a problem with the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check STARTUPINFO structure member 'StartupInfo.wShowWinodw' as below & give a fresh try..

```
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(StartupInfo));
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; //Set this flag to hide windows while create process.
```